# Authentication Via Servlet

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, servlets

I have a situation as below:

I have 2 web applications running on Tomcat. Initially User gets logged in to the Application 1 and then. There is a link to the Application 2. On Clicking the link User should be redirected to second application.

Both applications using LDAP authentication.

Now, the problem here is second application has its own Authentication system.

So, We are planning to implicitly authenticate the user which is logged in the first system.

I have written a servlet, which gets executed when I click on link for App2 in the App1.

I am trying to use below code which should call Servlet "ldap-login" on app2 with given parameters.Parameter names are correct.

```
String targetURL = "http://localhost:8080/app2/ldap-login";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    PostMethod doPost = new PostMethod(targetURL);

    //doPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(HttpMethodParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, true);
    doPost.addParameter("login_netid", "alice");
    doPost.addParameter("login_password", "alice");
    try {
        int status = client.executeMethod(doPost);
        if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
             // redirect
            response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/app2/myPage");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Service failed, Response Code= " +                  
                HttpStatus.getStatusText(status));  
            System.out.println("Response Body --> " + doPost.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("ERROR: " + 
         ex.getClass().getName() + " "+ ex.getMessage());
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
                doPost.releaseConnection();
      }
```

But I am getting Response "Moved temporarily".

Can anyone suggest me any alternate ?

Comment: How does it behave if you perform the same POST action from a browser (with a simple form submit)?

Comment: It behaves perfect when I perform the same using POST from browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 302 Moved Temporarily response is just a redirect. It's exactly the kind of response which you would get when you do `response.sendRedirect()`. You can also very good get a redirect as a response to a successful login. I suggest to verify on the second application if it isn't indeed redirecting when the login is successful. You should then check if the response code is 302 instead of 200. Or, alternatively, you need to tell `HttpClient` to follow any redirects automatically.

Even more, if the login actually failed, what kind of response would you get from the second application? Would it throw an exception and thus return a response code of 500? Or would it just conditionally set some error message in the request scope and redisplay the JSP by a forward and thus keep a response code of 200? How would you then distinguish a 200 on a failed login from a 200 on a successful login?

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your approach will likely not work if the second application does not share the same session as the first application. A login is usually stored in the session, but you're not maintaining the session anywhere. Anyway, that's subject for a new question :)

Comment: I have checked in Second Application. It does redirect on successful authentication and I think that's the reason I am getting 302 as response code.But page is not getting changed. It stays on same page after successful authentication. If you could suggest any alternate, It would be really appreciated.

Comment: It definitely is the reason you're getting a 302. The `response.sendRedirect()` sets by default a 302. See also http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3 If you're seeing the same page, then well, it just redirected to itself. This may be purposefully done to get a fresh new request, or be just bad design. Contact the author of that servlet for details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Well, The author is someone else whom I can not contact.I have already looked in to that servlet of Application 2 and modified the parameter to "String originalURL = "http://localhost:8080/jspui/mydspace";" and then response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(originalURL)); This the URL where I want to redirect the user.

Comment: @HardikMishra As per the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)), the `sendRedirect` call does a *temporary redirect*. As @BalusC mentioned, you need to handle response code `SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY` or `SC_FOUND`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29), the sendRedirect call does a temporary redirect. As @BalusC mentioned, you need to handle response code `SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY` or `SC_FOUND`.

The reason it's doing a redirect after login (or might be after any *POST* request) could be to avoid the [Double Submit Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). [Here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post) is another article on that one.